# How do I "Extract" the Value from an Angle in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm working with this Haskell library: AC-Angle

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/AC-Angle-1.0/docs/Data-Angle.html#t:Radians

Given a "Degree Float" type, I want to get the value of the float in that type, so that I can pass the value to a function that expects a Float.

How would I go about doing this or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Degrees` type is defined as

```
newtype Degrees x = Degrees x
```

Both the type and it's constructor are exported from the module. You can pattern match against it to get the single field.

```
getDegrees :: Degrees x -> x
getDegrees (Degrees x) = x
```

Comment: Thank you. so simple, Would it be possible to generalize the above function like: getValue:: a b -> b getValue (a b) = b? Haskell complains, why does it?

Comment: @user48133 No, for a lot of reasons. For example, many newtypes are defined which do not export their constructors, precisely to prevent you from peeking inside of them! Such a type must be viewed as opaque: you can only interact with it by passing it to functions which do know what it's made of.

Comment: @user5402, you should look into `Data.Coerce`. It's pretty cool stuff.

Comment: ok - I think a good explanation of the what's involved with a function like `getValue` would be beneficial, and that's why I would like the OP (or someone) to ask the question.